# Extracting array of frames from video using python open cv returns false and no image

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, opencv3.0

```
import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('9091694436881747630.mp4')

count = 0
success = True
while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
  if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     # exit if Escape is hit
      break
  count += 1
```

I used the above code to extract frames from mp4 video.

```
success,image = vidcap.read()
```

It should return a tuple of success flag and image as an [R,G,B] array. But however it returns false for all videos.

Comment: can you try to present the full filename? like `vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/username/folder/9091694436881747630.mp4')`? Can you try different videos, best with MJPG compression to be sure it is not a codec problem? If you dont have a video then just create a black image and write it several times to a cv2.VideoWriter with MJPG format setting and later try to open that file instead of the .mp4

Comment: I guess there is a problem with `vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/username/folder/9091694436881747630.mp4')` because even if I change the file name to a random filename which is not in the folder it has the same error. I tried to give the fullpath, It's still not fixing the problem.

Comment: However the following code works and gives the output
`fo = open("9091694436881747630.mp4", "r")

print("Name of the file: ", fo.name) 
# 9091694436881747630.mp4`

Comment: typically it is a codec problem. please try uncompressed or mjpg compressed files